# The Term Connect-ExchangeOnline is not recognized name of cmdlet, function, script file or operable program

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to connect with office365 PowerShell. I had also imported the module "ExchangeOnlineManagement". I'm getting the below exception:

"The term **Connect-ExchangeOnline** is not recognized as cmdlet, function , script or operable problem".

```
string script = @"
               Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
               $user = '<your username>'
               $pwd = '<your password>'
               $SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pwd -Force
               $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$SecurePass
               Import-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
               Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Cred
               ";
try
{
   using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
   {
      runspace.Open();
      Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
      pipe.Commands.AddScript(script);
      
      try
      {
         var results = pipe.Invoke();
      } 
      catch (Exception e)
      {

      }
      
      var error = pipe.Error.ReadToEnd();
      if (error.Count > 0)
      {
         foreach (PSObject err in error)
         {
            //more logging not sharing that code
         }
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

Comment: Any cmdlet has to be on the PSModulePath.  You can get value of path from cmd.exe >Set.  If you already downloaded the cmdlet than move it to an existing path.  Otherwise, see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

Comment: In addition to the PSModulePath listed above, you could have your program execute this command: 
get-module -ListAvailable    

which will show you all the modules your application's script host has access to

Comment: Get-Module -ListAvailable shows the list , There is also ExchangeOnlineManagement module available in list, but it throwing exception for import command "The specified module ExchangeOnlineManagement was not loaded because no valid module file found in any module directory". @MarkMascolino